# Creating custom id with mongo C# driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to set the Id property of my class as combination of another 2 properties:

```
   public class Student
   {
       public string Id {get;set;}
       public Guid StudentNumber {get;set;]
       public string SchoolId {get;set;}
   }
```

I want that StudentNumber and SchoolId to be the Id of the object when I save it.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the `IdGenerator` classes to custom create an id from the two properties.

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/

You'll need to create a new `IdGenerator` class which implements the `IIdGenerator` interface ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/)). There are two simple methods to implement.

Do note that a document's `_id` cannot be changed once saved. You'd need to resave it as a new document. So, if the `SchoolId` property changes, you may need to recreate the document.

Also, you might just consider creating a composite index for the two fields and leave the `_id` as an `ObjectId`.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150316203146/http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/

Comment: As this is a nearly 2.5 year old question -- this updated doc may not be relevant anymore. http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/bson/mapping/#id-generators